# Access tab loading image

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul, firefox-addon-sdk

Is it possible to access and trigger the tab loading image within a Firefox tab using jetpack? I want to create a jetpack that will trigger the tab loading image when it is performing a query but i'm not sure if this is even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what do you mean by "tab loading image"? Anyway, isn't [tabs module](https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/sdk/0.6/docs/#module/jetpack-core/tabs) exactly what you need?